# CSS rotate property for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Can anyone explain the conversion factor for the rotation number in Internet explorer, or how to use it properly?  For example:

```
       filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation= 1.8);   
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation= 1.8)";
copy-ms-transform:rotate(11.5deg);
```

I understand rotation in chrome because it's measured in degrees, but I'm not sure what this is using as its unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb554293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
iRotation specifies or receives one of the following values:
  0   Default. Content is not rotated.
  1   Content is rotated 90 degrees.
  2   Content is rotated 180 degrees.
  3   Content is rotated 270 degrees.
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Microsoft documentation:

> Sets or retrieves the value that indicates whether the content is rotated in ninety-degree increments.

So basically, `1` is equal to 90 degrees when using the BasicImage Rotation property. So a rotation of `1.8` is equal to a rotation of 162 degrees.

Comment: So how would I get a value like 11 degrees?  I tried using a decimal but it didn't do anything.

Comment: @Sam if you look at the documentation linked to in my answer, you'll see that it specifies that the input value is an `integer`, so it would appear rotations can only be made in 90º increments.

Comment: @Sam: Use math and rounding to get as close as possible? `11 / 90 = 0.1222` I don't really know how many decimal places it is limited too, if it's limited at all.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, yeah I assumed that, but I didn't want to believe it was so limited =/

Comment: @Andrew: I didn't see that. I just assumed it was decimal because there's so many examples around the web that use decimal values.